# Unable to override scss in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3, styles

I Have specified a global color for header in app.scss which is working fine but I want to change the color of a specific page header to black color but I can't find a way to  override header color from app.scss and change it to black color

my app.scss code

```
  .my-nav .toolbar .toolbar-background {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

how I am trying to override It in the other screen where I want it to be black

home.scss

```
  .my-nav .toolbar .toolbar-background {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The order of the imports should be as below

if you are importing in an scss file

```
 @import './app'
 @import './home'
```

if you are importing in a javascript file(your project must support import scss files in javascript)

```
import './app.scss'
import './home.scss'
```

Answer (score 0):

home.scss

```
.my-nav .toolbar .toolbar-background {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

give important to end of property automatically override other attributes